# Custom cut image from the top to the left bottom

Tags: html, css

how do i cut the image as shown here ( in css & html ):

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvQs2.png)

Comment: show as at least the code of the image ... in SO we don't ask for free coding, we do an effort and then we ask for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path). This lets you specify a polygonal shape over top an image. You can create a polygonal mask.

This article on css-tricks explains the concept: [link](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/).

Here's a tool that lets you generate your own clip-path, with a set of different polygonal shapes: [clippy](http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/).

Here's the code to generate a triangle that would fit your image:

```
-webkit-clip-path: polygon(13% 7%, 13% 88%, 57% 7%);
clip-path: polygon(13% 7%, 13% 88%, 57% 7%);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you, and how can i do like that ( sorry if i bother you ):
https://i.imgur.com/QXXWb1H.png

Comment: Copy the URL of that image to the editor I linked to (clippy), and experiment. You should be able to figure it out :)